# Delete emails with same subject text from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there an easy way to delete emails from Outlook where the emails have the same subject text?  I get a bunch of emails from internal system based on activity but I don't really need to keep them all, I really just need one (the latest would be the best).

I know I can sort by Subject and manually delete but that can be a bit tedious.

Comment: No other way out of the box. But you can use a third-party utility to remove duplicate messages. This utility needs to provide a way to select message subject only as a duplicate detection criteria. You can ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can use "Ctrl + A" to select all and delete them. Besides, you can also create a rule: Apply this rule after in the message arrives > With specific words in the subject > Permanently delete it. Then select "Run this  rule now on messages already in 'Inbox'".(Remember to backup the one you need.)